# IIS8: Redirect subdomain to specific port

Tags: redirect, port, subdomain, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I've got a Windows 2012 vServer with IIS8. I've some applications running on it like YouTrack or TeamCity.

From extern, I can point at them http://domain.tld:port/[query]. But I don't like that. What I want to have is http://youtrack.domain.tld/[query] which internally points to the correct address.

How to? :-)

(Since my reputation is < 300, I can not create the tag "ii8")

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question implies a lack of basic research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check IIS Application Request Routing (reverse proxy).

Comment: This answer needs a lot more details to be useful. If it is meant only as a hint on what to read about than make it a comment instead, not an answer.

Comment: Jep, it is working with application request routing. If you improve your answer, as @SvenW recommended, I'll mark it as an answer